# Irreconcilable dependencies in Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, amphp

I have two composer packages that require different versions of the same dependency. I have found answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493502/how-to-show-what-requires-a-package-in-composer) that help me diagnose the problem, but not how to resolve it.

Package A (`amphp/phpunit-util`) requires `phpunit/phpunit ^9`;
Package B (homegrown) requires `phpunit/phpunit ^11`.

I looked for some sort of option on the `require` command that would allow a package to be installed with the version it needs in a "sandboxed" way so that only Package A would use the old version, while other packages could use the new. I couldn't find anything, and barring autoload magic it seems a reach.

What are my options? Can I load `phpunit ^11` but somehow convince Package A that `phpunit ^9` is available?

Comment: You can't use composer to get two versions of the same package installed in the same project in parallel. Once a class is loaded by the autoloader it can't be unloaded to load a different version of the class.

Comment: `amphp/phpunit-util` looks pretty outdated. It hasn't seen any new release since more than a year, nor any other commits

Comment: Also, any sandboxed environment won't help if both packages should interact with the same instance of PHPUnit you're running. v9 and v11 are pretty far apart, so using a library that does not support v11 while running v11 is not possible

Comment: Yeah, v9 is out of date. Unfortunately, a change in v10 made it problematic for the async stuff in `amphp`. Right now it looks like they might create an entirely separate testing framework. Composer is loading entire `phpunit` versions locally, so there is a theoretical universe where the two could coexist. However, right now I'm just juggling `composer.json` in the package that uses `amphp`

Comment: There's no way to run code that needs v9 **and** v11 of PHPUnit, regardless of how you load them

Comment: I get that. It would require extreme autoload hijinks to get there (dynamic namespace modification, maybe?) which is basically what I said in my original post, though I called it 'magic' there. My only hope was there was a way to that I could LIE to one of them with an alias or something so each package could load, even if the tests only worked for one of them at a time.

Comment: No, that's not possible. As I've stated: v9 and v11 are so different that aliases (to classes that were renamed, but not completely reworked) won't help

Comment: Only if you need both to WORK. That would require major changes to Composer that would hardly be worth the effort. However, all I wanted was to allow Composer to stop refusing to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict in the package tree can be resolved by making sure that the divergent versions are always in the `require-dev` sections of the composer.json for the packages that use them. Then downstream packages will not try to load them.

In this case that makes sense because tests for each package should be scoped to the package itself.